# How to duplicate a directive with isolated scopes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

How can I push the inputted text from my directives to `$scope.output = []` on `ng-submit`?

**Check out live code:**
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/89AYX/30/)

I've created an anchor and attr directive `<a href="" data-clicker>add section</a>`  that appends an input field with an isolated scope inside a form.

**Directives:**

```
app.directive('clicker', function($compile) {
    'use strict';

    return {
        compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
            var t = '<div data-pop>Pop</div>';

            return function(scope, iElement) {
                iElement.click(function() {
                    $('.sections').append($compile(t)(scope));
                });
            };
        }
    }
});

app.directive('pop', function() {
    'use strict';

    return {
        scope: {
            name: '='
        },
        template: '<input type="text" ng-model="project.name" />'
//        templateUrl: 'partials/pop.html'
    };
});
```

**When i try to submit the form the the data isnt being pushed correctly.**

**html**

```
<div ng-app="miniapp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
     <a href="" data-clicker>add section</a>
    <form ng-model="project" ng-submit="addPage()">
        <div class="sections"></div>  

        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>

    <hr>
    <hr>
    <p>project: {{project.name | json}}</p> 
    <p>output: {{output | json}}</p> 
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.project = {"name":"sup"};
    $scope.output = [];
   $scope.addPage = function() {
     $scope.output.push($scope.project);     
   };
```

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/89AYX/31/ , and simply moved your inner directive to be where your outer directive is, and it looks to work as expected.

`var t = '<div><input type="text" ng-model="project.name"></div>';`

The issue seems to be that you are not compiling the inner input directive.

Comment: It does work now! however, the directives arn't isolated?  when you add muliple versions they repeate the same text

Comment: They repeat the same text, because the `ng-model` inside the directive points to the same scope object.

Comment: Is there a way we can merge the two ideas?  and have isolated scopes and compile so i can duplicate the inputfields